# How to set MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME for Gentoo?

Tags: gentoo, firefox

I'm trying set up MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME for Gentoo, but, no success! Searching in the Google, I found several ways for to fix the problem. However, I not found the xulrunner on my system.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? What kind of no-success do you have? Doesn't the variable get set or is it not respected by the particular package you are using. What is that program and what do you expect from it?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that this variable gets set by a script which then launches the application in question. For example the script `/usr/bin/application` sets `MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME` to `/usr/lib64/application` and executes the actual binary `/usr/lib64/application/application-bin`. But this should only matter if you create your own ebuild, not if you just want to use an existing ebuild. Perhaps running revdep-rebuild will help.